# CopyListBoxItem from one ListBox to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I have two ListBoxes. I want to copy `SelectedItem` from the first ListBox into Second one.

Why this code does not work ?

```
    private void frm_addDispatchBoard2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(propertiesManagementDataContext db = new propertiesManagementDataContext())
        {
            var Buildings = db.Buildings.Select(q => new { q.BuildingLandNumber, q.BuildingId });

            listBox_allBuildings.DataSource = Buildings;
            listBox_allBuildings.DisplayMember = "BuildingLandNumber";
            listBox_allBuildings.ValueMember = "BuildingId";
        }          
    }

    private void btn_addBuilding_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(listBox_allBuildings.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            listBox_selectedBuildings.Items.Add(listBox_allBuildings.SelectedItem);            
        }
    }
```

The result I got:

[image]

Comment: this is actually very simple have you thought about doing this for example in a foreach() loop If you like I can post a simple example

Comment: Sorry, why do I need to use foreach loop, if I need to copy only one item ?

Comment: because what if you have multiple selected Items silly

Comment: and to do a single move of the item this is also very simple.. looks like you had better read up on how to get at selectedItems and their value.. good luck

Comment: It did what you asked it to do.  The 2nd listbox is not bound to a collection so does not have a DisplayMember so you simply see the value produced by the item's ToString() method.  Surely you favor having it bound to a collection as well and actually move the item from one collection to the other.  Also avoids having to check that the user didn't add it twice.

Comment: OMG! The solution was so simple. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

try this I am not sure why you are looking for a Contains but if you really need that look at the difference between `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem`

> Use this code right here as a test to see if the expected value shows up in a MessageBox

```
string selected = listBox_allBuildings.GetItemText(listBox_allBuildings.SelectedValue);    
MessageBox.Show(selected);
```

this should help you to see the values in the Listbox on the right

```
private void btn_addBuilding_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBox_allBuildings.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
       var selected = listBox_allBuildings.GetItemText(listBox_allBuildings.SelectedValue);     
       listBox_selectedBuildings.Items.Add(selected);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. This code inserts only the value of the ValueMemeber.

Comment: then switch the SelectedValue to SelectedItem.Text

Comment: you can do this as well SelectedItem.ToString(); are you familiar with

Comment: Did you mean SelectedItem.ToString() ? It is still does not work.

Comment: I can't believe that it's not working I have tried a test on my end and works perfectly.. can you show more code perhaps you are leaving something out.. show exact updated code that you are trying I hope that you are not using the Contains because there is no need to

Comment: The message box displays the value of the ValueMemeber of the SelectedItem. As expected.

Comment: I will update the answer for the test to code that should work for you